# Dynamic Stylesheet with Redux framework

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, redux-framework

I have fall a problem to make stylesheet dynamic by redux. In my config.php I have write this code.

```
array(
    'id'        => 'scheme',
    'type'      => 'select',
    'title'     => __('Theme Stylesheet', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'subtitle'  => __('Select a predefined color scheme. They`re located in `/css/color-schemes/` theme folder', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'options'   => array('orange.css' => 'orange.css', 'red.css' => 'red.css', 'blue.css' => 'blue.css'),
    'default'   => 'orange.css',
),
```

and I have tried to enqueue stylesheet by writting bellow code on functions.php

```
if(!isset($redux_demo['scheme'])) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pm-color-scheme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/color-schemes/orange.css' );
}
else {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pm-color-scheme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/color-schemes/'.$redux_demo['scheme'] );
}
```

But when I select blue.css from theme option like this http://prntscr.com/3s5td0

I get default value that is orange.css everytime like this http://prntscr.com/3s5ucm.

what can I do now?

Comment: are you adding that enqueue style to an action?  Such as: add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');

Comment: yes, I have used this code bellow

Comment: if( !function_exists('delicious_enqueue_scripts') ) {
   
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','delicious_enqueue_scripts'); 
  
  function delicious_enqueue_scripts() {  

    if(!isset($redux_demo['scheme'])) {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'pm-color-scheme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/color-schemes/orange.css' );
    }
    else {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'pm-color-scheme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/color-schemes/'.$redux_demo['scheme'] );
    }
  }
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$redux_demo won't work until after your Redux Config has been run. Make sure you run it first.